# Use of Between Clause with Date on Timestamp Data Type Doesn't Give Correct Results

Tags: mysql, database

I have Table on SQL, The Table Name is "list_order" and i want to Filter data with BETWEEN Clause on field with the name of field is "date_order". Data Type of "data_order" is timestamp. I use Query :

> `select * from list_order where date_order between "2023-01-01" and "2023-12-31" and deleted_at is null;`

With the above query, I get invalid results. Sometimes the results are more or sometimes less. In fact, after the sampling results was carried out, no data changed.

I also tested using the query :

> `select * from list_order where date_order >= "2023-01-01" and date_order < "2023-12-31" and deleted_at is null;`

I don't know which query is the best, I just want the data retrieved to be accurate. sorry for my english. I'm still learning to speak English :(

Comment: "I get invalid results" - please can you share some example data?  Rows that were included but shouldn't be there, and rows that were not included that aren't returned?

Comment: Also note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so the two queries you have described are not equivalent.  "2023-12-31" would be included in the first query, but not in the second query.  If you're just trying to get everything in 2023, you could use `YEAR(date_order) = 2023` instead

Comment: Rob is correct in pointing out the difference between the two date ranges but avoid the suggested `YEAR(date_order) = 2023` approach, as it is non-[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: Your `date_order` datatype is TIMESTAMP. So your table stores not the value which you have saved into but the value converted to GMT timezone. And the date part of some values have been accordingly changed (it was incremented or decremented, depends on your client timezone shift value).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT * FROM list_order WHERE date_order BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-12-31'
```

or

```
select * from list_order where date_order >= '2023-01-01' and date_order < '2023-12-31'
```